# Video.js: Adding a menu to the control bar via plugin

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to a menu to the control bar of a video.js player via a plugin. Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/qisec/1/edit) of my end goal. The problem is that the demo is adding a menu to the control bar in video.js itself whereas I want a plugin that adds a menu.

So far I have been able to create a plugin that adds a `MenuButton` to the control bar, but I'm unable to populate the menu with any menu items.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jUCu2/2/) of where I'm at now.

The problem is when I try to create a new `PlaybackRateMenuItem` object with `new videojs.PlaybackRateMenuItem(this, {rate: rates[i] + 'x'})`. The JS console throws the following error on line 805 of `video.dev.js`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'guid' of undefined
```

This corresponds to the following function in the unminified version:

```
vjs.bind = function(context, fn, uid) {
    // Make sure the function has a unique ID
    if (!fn.guid) {
        fn.guid = vjs.guid++;
    }

    ... omitted ...
};
```

Or more specifically, this line: `if (!fn.guid) {`.

From stepping through in a debugger, I see that `fn` is being passed in as `undefined` and the caller of the function is:

```
vjs.bind(this.player(), this.player().reportUserActivity);
```

When this function is being called, `this.player()` returns a defined value, but once `vjs.bind` is called, both arguments become undefined and I have no idea why. Any ideas or a point in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had two major problems here.

1. Overriding the `createMenu` method instead of the `createItems` method for my class that extended the `videojs.MenuButton` class.
2. The `this` argument to the constructor of the `videojs.MenuItem` class must be the videojs player object, not just `this`. Problem is that the name of this object is mangled in the minified version of video.js. For this situation, I found that using `this.c` was the player object, but overall, I found it easier to just use the unminified version, `video.dev.js`, and not have to deal with the name mangling. In that case, using `this.player_` was correct.